# find IP address of a device

Tags: networking, ip

I have multiple devices connceted to an [HP 1910-48g managed switch](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/networking-switches/product-detail.html?oid=4218346) . Three of them are fingerprint scanner devices. We use them for time attendance reports.

Because of some problems I have to reinstall software but in order to configure the software I need to find their IP addresses. I was able to find one of device's IP address from old software. For the rest of them I tried a network scanner but I couldn't find the addresses.

Perhaps they are on a different subnet. Is there any way to narrow the search down?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. More details are needed. You haven't given us enough detail to be able to help you. Take a minute to read **[ask]** to improve your question.

Comment: I find Zenmap is great for finding unknown devices. there is no gaurentee that it will be able to identify the device exactly, but it often provides the required clues, even if the vendor/OS version cannot be infered from the scan.

Comment: [This might work for you](http://www.iplocation.net/find-private-network-ip)

Comment: @FrankThomas is right, nmap too is great to make a map from a network, be carefull some sniffing features make a firewall to block the conectivity.

Comment: I already installed nmap and I am trying to understand how to use it :)

Comment: Wireshark will help you...

Comment: What is make and model of scanner.

Comment: I don't think maker or model will help . I think they are chinese and customised by local manifacturer. Model is MA300

Comment: You said you think they are on a different subnet.  Why?  Was the one IP you found on a different subnet?  What is the network layout?

Comment: I use 192.168.1.1/24 and 192.168.2.1/24. Ip adress of the one which I found is: 169.254.167.224

Comment: hmmmm, 169.254.x.y is a zero-conf address, designed to be used in conjunction with discovery protocols and software. It should only be present when DHCP fails, because it will not be able to connect to other hosts on the 192.168.x.y networks.

Answer (score 1):

This will work if the scanner has static IP.

1. Disconnect the *scanner* from HP 1910-48g and put in on a separated switch or hub.
2. Connect a PC running Wireshark on other port of the switch / hub.
3. Turn off the scanner, connect it to the switch /hub and turn it on.
4. On Wireshark you will find ARP packets sent by the scanner. Clearly you will see the IP address of the scanner.

Comment: unfurtunatly cables are not marked and scanners mounted to wall. I would like to avoid dismount them. Of course I'll do as you suggested if there are no other way.

Comment: Even if they’re unmarked you’ll be able to see if you’re using the scanner you separated. After that, don’t forget to label the cables. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your switch offers you some tools that could be helpful.  I'll start with some tools you already have that might be of use, and we'll go from there.

First, your switch likely keeps an MAC address table.  There is a chance you can access it from the switch's UI.  If you can, download it and open it in a spreadsheet tool.  It may well help you find out which port the device is plugged into.

Simplest way is to take the device you have found, determine the first three octets (6 digits) of the MAC address (using an ARP tool to get the MAC from the IP address) and look for other MAC addresses that start with the same numbers.  You can then use the MAC address table to locate which switch port they are plugged into, and do a more focused test.

Second, you have the device itself.  If it behaves differently when network connected, you can simply toggle the switch ports one at a time until you locate the correct port.  Alternatively, if you can control the power to the devices, you can note which switch ports are link-up, power off the readers, and then see which ports went link-down when the power was cut to the device.

Third, you can go on a cable-tracing expedition.  If you have a plenum ceiling, it probably isn't too hard, but you need a ladder and a flashlight and time.  The cable will come out of the wall above the drop-ceiling near the reader, and you can probably follow it with your eyes a good distance.

Fourth, your switch supports VLANs.  This means that you don't strictly need to unplug the badge readers once you've identified the ports; you can put them on their own VLAN with your device running WireShark and experiment from there.

Once you have the ports, the other answers are good ways to get the IP addresses, but I suggest that you will likely want to provide a consistent IP address over time using a DHCP server that supports MAC address based registrations for the long term.